# Change amount of time Bootstrap tooltips display / fade in and out

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm adding tooltips using Twitter Bootstrap, is there an attribute I can add which determines how long a tooltip displays for / how long it takes to fade in and out?

```
<span class="myClass" data-tooltip="{{myData}}" data-tooltip-placement="right"></span>
```

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bootstrap uses the class `.fade` for the opacity change of the tooltips. It looks like this in the CSS file:

```
.fade {
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .15s linear;
    -o-transition: opacity .15s linear;
    transition: opacity .15s linear;
}
```

Just change the `.15s` of the transition properties to your desired duration.